# Flutter showing error which was already resolved. I'm using getter "map" instead of "values" but it still showing previous error

Tags: flutter, firebase-realtime-database

Flutter is showing previous error which I already resolved and i don't even using "values" getter now but it still showing the same previous error. I have already tried "flutter clean" but it didn't helped.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qUNfS.png)

Comment: Show us your code

Comment: Map map  = snapshot.data.snapshot.values;

                dataList.clear();

                map.forEach((index, map) => {
                      dataList.add({"key": index, ...map})
                    });
                return GridView.builder(
                  gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                      crossAxisCount: 4),
                  itemCount: dataList.length,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, index) =>
                      Text(dataList[index].dayno.toString()),

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. Also see: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 0):

> i don't even using "values" getter now

Yes you do. it's in this line:

```
Map map = snapshot.data.snapshot.values;
```

I believe it needs to be

```
Map map = snapshot.data.snapshot.value;
```

Comment: That's what I'm saying, I'm not using "values" but the error says that i'm using it. Basically, it's showing me the previous error which is already resolved.

Comment: @ManzurKhan the fact that it's written there means you are using `values`!

Comment: no, i'm not. Have a look at the above screenshot i posted

Comment: @ManzurKhan , dude it's right there `snapshot.data.snapshot.values;` that ends with **values**

Comment: OMG. I can't believe it. How can i be so dumb....